# How can I detect what version of macOS my Cmake code is running on?

Tags: macos, cmake, cmake-language

I need to determine what version of MacOS the cmake file is running on.

```
if(BIGSUR)
     # do something
else()
    #  do something else
endif()
```

Comment: Have you checked [CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION.html) variable? According to its description, you can use it for your purpose.

Comment: Yes that looks like exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing, `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION` might not be correct. You might instead want `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` which gives the version of the target system for which you are compiling. The wording in your question ("the cmake file is running on") suggests that you do want the `HOST` version, but I'm mentioning both for completeness.

Now, what you probably want is:

```
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin" 
    AND CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 20
    AND CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION VERSION_LESS 21)
    message(STATUS "Running on Big Sur")
endif ()
```

Note that Big Sur is the latest version of macOS and runs the Darwin kernel version 20.x. Each release of macOS has increased the Darwin major version by 1 since Jaguar in 2002 (Puma jumped from v1.4.1 to 5.1), so it's safe to assume that no release of Big Sur will have a Darwin version > 20.